# Application that Recovers Disk Contents in RAW form and Dumps as One Big Binary File?

Tags: c++, disk

I have a bunch of work that was lost on a hard drive that I had accidentally formatted at one time. I realize there are many data recovery tools out there, but all of them seem to try and scan the drive for actual partition data to recover files. I don't need this. **I simply need a program to access each sector in a RAW fashion and dump the contents, byte-by-byte, to some file.** The reason being, is that most of my work are ASCII files, so I don't care if the contents are part of a recognizable and complete file. I'm OK with parsing through the RAW data and trying to recover whatever text I can.

So does something like this exist, or am I resigned to code my own program (something I'm more than OK with)? It'd be a rather simple program that literally would scan the entire disk (sector by sector) and dump the contents (byte by byte) to a file (or likely several smaller files to make it more manageable) on another disk. **What's the suggested way to make RAW disk reads from C/C++?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you boot from a Linux [Live CD](http://livecdlist.com/), identify the device name of the hard disk (eg with `fdisk` which will also tell you the partition size) then use the [dd](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_dd.htm) command, eg `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/mnt/path_to_external_drive` to extract the raw contents of the disk?

Comment: Nice. That looks like it'll be simple enough. Thanks, I'll try this later today.